# Pyspark replace NA by searching another column for the same value

Tags: python, pyspark

Values from Column_1 can't have multiple values on column_2. So, for the same Id we have the same value.

```
column_1 column_2
    52     A
    78     B
    52
```

Expected

```
column_1 column_2
    52     A
    78     B
    52     A
```

Which means searching column_1 for the first column_1 value that matchs the same missing column_2 id.

I've a working solution using R, but using pyspark I couldn't find a similar approach.

Answer (score 2):

Since the same ID will always have the same value, as you have stated

One way to achieve this is to use the inherent sequence order present within your data and use the `lag` value to populate the missing values

You can utilise [Lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html) Function to generate the previous value associated to your `col_1` and [Coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) to get the first non-null value from the two

#### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col_1': [52,78,52,52,78,78],
        'col_2': ['A','B',None,'A','B',None]
})

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|
+-----+-----+
|   52|    A|
|   78|    B|
|   52| null|
|   52|    A|
|   78|    B|
|   78| null|
+-----+-----+
```

#### Lag

```
window = Window.partitionBy('col_1').orderBy(F.col('col_2').desc())
    
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('col_2_lag',F.lag('col_2').over(window))
    
sparkDF.show()

+-----+-----+---------+
|col_1|col_2|col_2_lag|
+-----+-----+---------+
|   52|    A|     null|
|   52|    A|        A|
|   52| null|        A|
|   78|    B|     null|
|   78|    B|        B|
|   78| null|        B|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

#### Coalesce

```
sparkDF  = sparkDF.withColumn('col_2',F.coalesce(F.col('col_2'),F.col('col_2_lag'))).drop('col_2_lag')
                
sparkDF.show()

+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|
+-----+-----+
|   52|    A|
|   52|    A|
|   52|    A|
|   78|    B|
|   78|    B|
|   78|    B|
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, using `max` :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df.withColumn(
    "column_2",
    F.coalesce(
        F.col("column_2"), F.max("column_2").over(Window.partitionBy("column_1"))
    ),
).show()
```